# Retrieve historical data stored as text via R Bloomberg API

Tags: r, bloomberg

I am trying to run code similar to the one below to retrieve Bloomberg data that is stored as "Yes", "No".

```
library(Rblpapi)
bdh('AAPL US Equity', c('SAME_PERSON_CEO_AND_CHMN','CEO_PROMOTED_WITHIN_COMPANY',
'FEMALE_CEO_OR_EQUIVALENT'), start.date=Sys.Date()-370)
```

However, I keep getting this error message:

```
Error in bdh_Impl(con, securities, fields, start.date, end.date, options,  : 
  Attempt to access value of element 'SAME_PERSON_CEO_AND_CHMN'(type: 'Float64') as 'bool' type.
```

I have tried to add this option to fix it, but that doesn't work:

```
int.as.double = getOption("blpIntAsDouble", TRUE)
```

Thank you

Comment: Where is the blpConnect() ?

Comment: I didn't include that, but here it is: blpConnect(host = getOption("blpHost", "localhost"),
           port = getOption("blpPort", 8194L), default = TRUE)